# LAN transfers same speed as internet transfers

Tags: router, lan

Downloads from the internet (either torrents or direct- ftp or http) and going at the same speed as transfers over the LAN.

Both PC's (ubuntu) transfers and internet downloads top out at 11 MB/s.

LAN should be much faster, no?

Perhaps some limitation in the router's default settings?

Router model number is Linksys E1200, which is relatively a fairly recent model, only a couple years old.  It's topped out at that speed every since it was new- I only noticed just now that the speed is the same for both LAN and internet.

Both are going over ethernet cable, not WAN.

Comment: There are still a lot of factors might influencing speed: network cards, type of cables (e.g. cat5), exact way you measure speed... Also you should measure speed directly between two computers without the router to learn whether limitation really comes from the router.

Comment: Ok some more info:
I ran:

iperf -s

And 

iperf -c <IP_on_Ubuntu_With_Samba>

And got the same speed.

Connection directly?  So I should just plug the cat5 directly and then what?  How do I do a transfer if neither has a local IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming "11 MB/s" means 11 MebiBytes per second, that's 92 megabits per second, which is pretty close to the 94 megabit per second theoretical maximum throughput that you can achieve with TCP over IPv4 over 100Mbps Ethernet using standard 1500-byte frames.

The Linksys E1200 is very old and slow by modern standards. Its Ethernet ports max out at 100Mbps, and its Wi-Fi is only 300Mbps 802.11n, which was introduced in late 2006. Even if the E1200 is a little more recent than that, and even if it overstayed its welcome in Linksys' product lineup, it's still using technology from 2007.

Comment: Wait so am I understanding this correctly- the wifi on this can go as high a 300Mbps but the cat5 cable can only do 100?  The wifi is faster than the cable?

Comment: @Squatcobbler Yes, the Wi-Fi on that box can do 300 Mbps nominally (~200 Mbps or less in real throughput), but no matter what copper-quality grade of Ethernet cable you attach to it (Cat5, 5e, 6, 6a, etc) it has no ability to transmit faster than 100Mbps over the cable. It only supports 10BASE-T and 100BASE-T[X] Ethernet signalling standards. The quality grade of the copper cable doesn't affect the speed, as long as it meets the minimum requirements for 100BASE-TX, which is Cat5.

Comment: My jaw is dropping. Well, unfortunately I'm in ubuntu and usb wifi adapters are notoriously difficult-to-impossible to get working in linux.  Anyway, that's for another help post.  I'll mark this solved.